# Can we merge two branches and keep it another branch (ie. not master) through github

Tags: github, branch

I have 4 branches...
`B1` is master
`B2` is next to master
`B3`,`B4` are sub branches

I like to merge `B3` and `B4` and keep it `B2`.

Is this possible, if yes, how?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Could you show us a diagram of the branches and what you want to do?

Comment: 1. B1 master 1.1. B2 1.1.1. B3 1.1.2. B4 this  is the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Pull B4 in B3 then merge B3 in B2

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout b3`

`get merge b4`

`get checkout b2`

`git merge b3`